# Binding ComboBox data to ListView Data in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to generate a WPF modal containing combo box inside List views.
The combo-box will be generated dynamically and requires binding.

### XAML Code

```
<ListView Height="291" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,196,0,0" Name="filterByList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="303" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,50,34,0" Name="filterName" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,50,34,0" Name="filterValues" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=filterByValues}" IsEnabled="True" SelectedIndex="0" SelectedValuePath="filterByValues" DisplayMemberPath="filterByValues" />
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

### Code-Behind

```
     List<Dimension> dimensionsData = new List<Dimension>();
            List<filterByValues> filterByValuesData = new List<filterByValues>();
            JArray filterByObject = JArray.Parse("[ { 'DisplayName': 'Fund', 'Values': [ 'FundA', 'FundB', 'FundC' ] }, { 'DisplayName': 'Sector', 'Values': [ 'SectorA', 'SectorB', 'SectorC' ] }, { 'DisplayName': 'Country', 'Values': [ 'CountryA', 'CountryB', 'CountryC' ] } ]");

            foreach (JObject value in filterByObject)
            {
                filterByValuesData = new List<filterByValues>();
                String JsonName = (String)value.GetValue("JsonName");
                String DisplayName = (String)value.GetValue("DisplayName");
                JArray Values = (JArray)value.GetValue("Values"); 
                foreach (var item in Values)
                {
                    filterByValuesData.Add(new filterByValues((string)item)); 
                }
                dimensionsData.Add(new Dimension { DisplayName = DisplayName, filterByValues = filterByValuesData }); 
            }
            filterByList.ItemsSource = dimensionsData;

 public class Dimension
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public List<filterByValues> filterByValues { get; set; }
    }

  public class filterByValues{
      public string filter{ get; set; }
      public filterByValues(String val) {
          filter = val;
      }
    }
```

The combo box generated is empty. I am very new to C# and WPF.

Comment: •`filterByList.ItemsSource = dimensionsData;` why? •`Path=filterByValues` where `filterByvalues` is getting updated?

Comment: Hi Prajwal, i am binding dimensionData(which is Dimension type) to list. and binding filterByValues (which is list attribute of dimensionData) to comboBox in xaml. I am very new to wpf. pls let me know if i am doing anything worng here.

Comment: I think you need to create a Dependency Property for filterByvalues for it to work, bindings work with existing property's, if you would like your own property then you need to define it as a dependency property

Comment: First advice => Do not use the designer to create your interface, just use it to know what you will get. This margins="0,50,34,0" indicates this.
Second advice => Binding is not easy to get a first if you don't know how WPF works. So you should first try to populate your list via code behind.
Once you understand how wpf controls works look for some mvvm frameworks, this way you will be able to use the full power of binding :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like problem is in your binding expression for ComboBox

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,50,34,0" Name="filterValues" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=filterByValues}" IsEnabled="True" SelectedIndex="0" SelectedValuePath="filterByValues" DisplayMemberPath="filterByValues" />
```

You don't need a relative source binding in item source, the DataTemplate will be applied to all items being rendered. You can try

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,50,34,0" Name="filterValues" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107" ItemsSource="{Binding filterByValues}" IsEnabled="True" SelectedIndex="0" SelectedValuePath="filter" DisplayMemberPath="filter" />
```

If it still don't work, have a look on the Visual Studio output window, It outputs the binding error in details. You can share it here if that is the case.